# How are vector spaces of polynomials defined?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

In a practice question, I'm asked to prove that $\mathbb{P}^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{P}^3$. This is pretty straightforward, but I was realizing I had a hard time formalizing it because I wasn't sure *exactly* how vectors in $\mathbb{P}^n$ are defined. For example, if they are defined as tuples, then its not true that $\mathbb{P}^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{P}^3$. For example, $[0,0,0] \in \mathbb{P}^2$ but $[0,0,0] \notin \mathbb{P}^3$. All elements in $\mathbb{P}^3$ are 4-tuples, but all elements in $\mathbb{P}^2$ are 3-tuples. One way that would seem to work would be $\{(t,p(t))|t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and p(t) is in the form $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i$.
How is the vector space $\mathbb{P}^n$ defined, and is it always defined in the same way?

Comment: Define the set $\mathbb P^2$ to be the set of all polynomials of degree $0 \le n \le 2$ and similarly $\mathbb P^3$ to be set of all polynomials of degree $0 \le n \le 3$. What is difficult about it

Comment: You could define a polynomial as a (countably) infinite tuple $(a,b,c,...)$. Then $\mathbb{P^n}$ would consist of elements of form $(u_0, ..., u_n, 0,...)$ with only the first $n+1$ terms being non-zero.

Comment: Physor-- I agree, its not so difficult, I'm more just curious on how exactly its defined. It seems to be that when it comes to sets, theres often more than one valid way to define something, but the precise definition is not mentioned in my textbook and in this instance the precise definition matters. That being said, I'm still definitely a beginner so maybe I'm misunderstanding something crucial and obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you define the vector space of all polynomials $P$, however you want; there are several equivalent ways to do this but the important thing is to pick one. My preferred definition is that it consists of formal sums $\sum a_i x^i$ but some people don't like formal sums and do other stuff.

Then you define the degree of a polynomial. Then $P_n \subset P$ is the subspace of $P$ of polynomials of degree at most $n$. In particular there are canonical inclusions $P_n \subseteq P_m$ whenever $n \le m$.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you first construct all polynomials. Then, you make degree an ordering such that if $P_n \subset P$ and $P_m \subset P$, then $P_n \subset P_m \iff n < m$? Would any definition of degree work so long as it follows those rules, and does there exist any non-standard definition so degree that would pass these requirements? For example, if I made the base something like $\{1-x+3x^2,2+x+x^2,-2-2x+x^2,...\}$, could I assign a polynomial degree 0 if its basis is only the first vector, degree 1 if it includes the first two vectors, degree 2 the first three, etc.?

Comment: @Caleb: when people talk about the degree of a polynomial they are talking about a specific function, which can be defined in several equivalent ways (e.g. the largest $n$ such that there is a nonzero term $a_n x^n$). You can define a different collection of subspaces of $P$ inducing a different notion of degree if you want, and sometimes there are good reasons to do things like this, but it won't be what people mean when they say "degree of a polynomial."

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now. If I’m correct, it’s possible for any base of polynomials to define a sub-space ordering by just adding a new linearly independent vector from the basis we choose. For the usually monomial bases, we call this ordering the degree. Other bases have their own ordering, but we don’t call this ordering the degree since that’s only a good characterization for a monomial basis. Is that right?

Comment: @Caleb: yes, that's right. In more than one variable there's still the usual notion of degree for a multivariate polynomial but sometimes you'd like a more specific ordering and then people use what are called monomial orders, of which there are many, suited for different applications: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order